# How to perform cleaning operations on all tables in a database based on actions in a table

Tags: sql-server

I am not sure how to word this, and it might be easy, but I have one table with a list of actions for several variables

Example of data:

```
Table=X
Variable=AccountNumber
Action=Set to blank (written in SQL code)
```

I want the code to go to `X.accountnumber` and perform action, and do this for all the table/variables  combination in a particular database

I assume I will need dynamic SQL for this? I am just trying to figure out how to get started in doing a column by column search for each table and if the column matches, call the action from the action table

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the undocumented stored procedure sp_msforeachtable.

[See here for more info](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031/SQL-Server-Undocumented-Stored-Procedures-spMSforeachtable-and-spMSforeachdb.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Jeffrey Van Laethem, more information here
[sp_MSforeachtable](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/04/8-common-uses-of-undocumented-stored.html)